# MAC adressess found on multiple ports

Tags: awk, sed

I have processed an access log with :

```
grep -o -w -E '[[:alnum:]:]{17}.*[0-9]' testlog | awk '{print $1 " " $3}'
```

Which results in the following (obfuscated)

```
1.01:03:96:51:9A:31 3:37
2.01:03:96:51:9A:31 3:39
3.00:E0:2B:00:00:01 3:39
4.3C:A9:F4:1C:68:A4 3:37
5.01:01:96:51:A6:5E 3:39
6.01:01:96:51:A6:5E 3:39
```

How do I print all MACs that are found on multiple ports (in the example ) rows 1-2 and 5-6 ?

Comment: what do you mean by multiple ports?

Comment: Post some of the `testlog` and what you like to get out of it.

Comment: :) Monday morning and fully asleep


Multiple unique ports. I.e  MAC (01:03:96:51:9A:31) is found on ports 3:37 and 3:39.

Comment: Why do you want 5th and 6th rows?

Comment: There goes the log, to skip further misunderstanding due to lack of coffee :D

`code`
 Aug 22 13:06:20 nl: Slot-11: Network Login MAC user  logged in MAC 3C:A9:F4:1C:68:A4 port 6:37 
 Aug 22 13:06:21 nl: Slot-11: Network Login MAC user  logged in MAC 02:04:96:51:A6:5E port 6:39 
 Aug 22 13:06:21 nl: Slot-11: Network Login MAC user  logged in Mac 02:04:96:51:A6:5E port 6:39
 Aug 22 13:06:21 nl: Slot-11: Network Login MAC user  logged in MAC 02:04:96:51:A6:5E port 6:37 
 Aug 22 13:08:20 nl: Slot-11: Network Login MAC user  logged in MAC 3C:A9:F4:1C:68:A4 port 6:39 
`code`

Comment: @AtanasMitev Posted the log in your original post. The formatting in comments, does make it unreadable.

Comment: @AtanasMitev Click `edit` below your original post and enter the output there.  I guess we can do all this with one command.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this input:

```
cat file
01:03:96:51:9A:31 3:37
01:03:96:51:9A:31 3:39
00:E0:2B:00:00:01 3:39
3C:A9:F4:1C:68:A4 3:37
01:01:96:51:A6:5E 3:39
01:01:96:51:A6:5E 3:39
```

You can do

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' file
01:03:96:51:9A:31 3:37
01:03:96:51:9A:31 3:39
00:E0:2B:00:00:01 3:39
3C:A9:F4:1C:68:A4 3:37
01:01:96:51:A6:5E 3:39
```

or

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' file | sort -k2
01:03:96:51:9A:31 3:37
3C:A9:F4:1C:68:A4 3:37
00:E0:2B:00:00:01 3:39
01:01:96:51:A6:5E 3:39
01:03:96:51:9A:31 3:39
```

Comment: That won't work as each line has a new number at the start. Maybe try something like `awk -F. '!x[$2]++' file`

Comment: @Jidder I will guess OP just added line number. That is why I did ask him to update post with log data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need like this?

```
awk '{ seen[$1]++; } END{ for(idx in seen){ if(seen[idx] != 1 ) print idx }}' file
```

Input file:

```
01:03:96:51:9A:31 3:37
01:03:96:51:9A:31 3:39
00:E0:2B:00:00:01 3:39
3C:A9:F4:1C:68:A4 3:37
01:01:96:51:A6:5E 3:39
01:01:96:51:A6:5E 3:39
```

Output:

```
$ awk '{ seen[$1]++; } END{ for(idx in seen){ if(seen[idx] != 1 ) print idx }}' file
01:01:96:51:A6:5E
01:03:96:51:9A:31
```

Answer (score 0):

You never need grep if you're using awk. You don't show what your original `testlog` looks like so while this will probably produce the output you want, it may not be the best way to do it since it's just using the logic from your grep but there may be a better way in awk:

```
awk '
match($0,/[[:alnum:]:]{17}.*[0-9]/) {
    ip = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    print ip
    sub(/ .*/,"",ip)
    count[ip]++
}
END {
    for (ip in count) {
        if (count[ip] > 1) {
            printf "IP %s occurs %d times\n", ip, count[ip] | "cat>&2"
        }
    }
}
' testlog
```